# Table layout with tabularx (column widths: 50%|25%|25%)

Tags: tables, tabularx

This code produces a table with three centered column:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| c | c | c |}
        \hline
        Alpha     & Beta     & Gamma     \\ \hline
        0         & 2        & 4         \\ \hline
        1         & 3        & 5         \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

This code produces a full-width table with columns of equal width:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
        \hline
        Alpha     & Beta     & Gamma     \\ \hline
        0         & 2        & 4         \\ \hline
        1         & 3        & 5         \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

I can't get how to produce full-width table, with centered header (~ first row) and columns of width `|50%|25%|25%|` respectively?

Would be nice if I could define these styles somewhere at the beginning of the document, so that all further tables will be able to use it.

Comment: See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabularx_package_-_simple_column_stretching

Comment: @mythealias Yes, of course I've been there, but haven't found solution (or maybe haven't understood it), so I am asking here. :)

Comment: It is the third example for `tabularx`, but for some reason they do it in a convoluted manner by combining two columns. Also no harm in asking, I was just being lazy to write an answer :)

Comment: OK, thank you. I think, reading convoluted code is often useful for general understanding. So, I'll try to figure out example from your link.

Comment: it is actually similar to the answer posted by cmhughes below. only that the space between second and third column is removed and the columns are right and left justified instead of being centered.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The code below defines two new `columntypes`: `b` for 'big' and `s` for 'small'

I followed the details of section 4.3 of the [`documentation`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/tabularx.pdf) to create these.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{bss}
        \hline
        Alpha     & Beta     & Gamma     \\ \hline
        0         & 2        & 4         \\ \hline
        1         & 3        & 5         \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you'd like to center the heading, then you can use something like the following, which defines a `\heading` command to center its argument

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{bss}
        \hline
        \heading{Alpha}     & \heading{Beta}     & \heading{Gamma}     \\ \hline
        0         & 2        & 4         \\ \hline
        1         & 3        & 5         \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the total with has to be 3\hsize so if you have 2 s then b should be \hsize=2\size so you have 2+.5+.5=3

Comment: For me, the `b` and `s` approach didn’t quite work, when I needed `{|sb|}`. The right border went a centimeter or so inside the table. So I used `\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.25\hsize \raggedright\arraybackslash}X} \newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=.75\hsize}X}` and `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|sb|}` which looks fine, though I don’t really know what all of the commands are doing, so I’m unaware of a better approach.

Answer (score 18):

Knowing that each column has two "tab separators" and 4/3's of an `\arrayrulewidth`, you can subtract that from a regular `p`-column specifier:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
  \hline
   Alpha     & Beta     & Gamma     \\ \hline
   0         & 2        & 4         \\ \hline
   1         & 3        & 5         \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{
  |p{\dimexpr.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 1
  |p{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 2
  |p{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}|% column 3
  }
  \hline
  \centering Alpha     & \centering Beta     & \centering\arraybackslash Gamma     \\ \hline
  0         & 2        & 4         \\ \hline
  1         & 3        & 5         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Centering is obtained using `\centering` within the required cell (knowing that you're dealing with a `p`-column, this is possible). The modification of this alignment requires a small correction (via `\arraybackslash`) to re-establish the use of `\\` in a `tabular`.

Answer (score 12):

My new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={|X[2]|X|X|}, row{1} = {c}, hlines,
    }
      Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
        0   &  2   &   4   \\
        1   &  3   &   5   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As `tabu` (outdated) and `tabularray`, the package `nicematrix` provides weight of the `X` columns of its environment `{NiceTabular}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|X[2]|X|X|}[hlines]
      Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
        0   &  2   &   4   \\
        1   &  3   &   5   \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use the `tabu` environment. You can give "weights" (width coefficients) to `X` columns (`X[2]`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {| X[2] | X | X |}
        \hline
        \centering Alpha & \centering Beta & \centering Gamma \\ \hline
        0                & 2               & 4                \\ \hline
        1                & 3               & 5                \\ \hline
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Future reader: Please do not use this proposal because of https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu.

Answer (score 1):

Simple like that

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% table
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.25\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.25\hsize}X|}
        \hline
        Alpha     & Beta     & Gamma     \\ \hline
        0         & 2        & 4         \\ \hline
        1         & 3        & 5         \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works by chance. It should be `\hsize=1.5\hsize` for the first column and `\hsize=0.75\hsize` for the other two.