# Redefinition of tabularx column not applying to all columns

Tags: tabularx

I obeserve a strange behaviour when trying to get text vertically centered in `tabularx` cells. According to a suggestion, I tried `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` which works so far as it goes. But I have three columns, only two of which appear to be affected.
Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl,xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
   \begin{center}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|X|}
         \hline
         Chomsky-Typ & Name der Sprachfamilie & Automaten \\
         \hline\hline\hline
         0 & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}rekursiv aufzählbar & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}(N)DTM \\[1em]
         \hline
         \cellcolor{lightgray!20}1 & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}kontext-sensitiv & NLBA \\[1em]
         \hline
         \cellcolor{lightgray!20}3 & regulär & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}(N)DEA \\[1em]
         \hline
         hu & ha & he \\[1em]
         \hline
      \end{tabularx}
   \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output. As you see, the right `X` coulumn is unaffected.
[image]

I am at a loss. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the extra space of `\\[1em]` being effectively added to the text within the last cell in the row, thus preventing that cell from being centered - see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/how-to-specify-the-row-height-in-latex-table).

Thus in order to get your content centered and be able to specify row height, you need to add another, empty, column to your table, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl,xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\newlength\origtabcolsep
\origtabcolsep=\tabcolsep
\tabcolsep=0pt
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{e}{>{\hsize=0pt}X}
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\hskip\origtabcolsep}X<{\hskip\origtabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hskip\origtabcolsep}c<{\hskip\origtabcolsep}}
   \begin{center}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C|x|xe|}
         \hline
         Chomsky-Typ & Name der Sprachfamilie & Automaten &\\
         \hline\hline\hline
         0 & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}rekursiv aufzählbar & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}(N)DTM &\\[1em]
         \hline
         \cellcolor{lightgray!20}1 & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}kontext-sensitiv & NLBA &\\[1em]
         \hline
         \cellcolor{lightgray!20}3 & regulär & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}(N)DEA & \\[1em]
         \hline
         hu & ha & he &\\[1em]
         \hline
      \end{tabularx}
   \end{center}
\tabcolsep=\origtabcolsep
\end{document}
```

[image: output table]

The specification of the empty column was inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84400/table-layout-with-tabularx-column-widths-502525). *Edit*: I fixed the white space at the right hand side of the table by introducing new column types allowing to set `\tabcolsep` to `0pt` temporarily.

Comment: This does do the trick. One would think there was a simpler solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another approach: with the `cellspace` package, define a minimal vertical spacing between the top of a cell and the above cell,  and similarly aminimal spacing between the bottom of a cell and the top of the below cell. There remains to prefix the column specifier with `S`. It works by default with the `l, r, c` specifier, and with the `X` type if you dclare so in preamble. Here is an example (values to be adjusted to your taste):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl,xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{10pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{10pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{{X}}


\begin{document}

   \begin{center}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|S{X}|}
         \hline
         Chomsky-Typ & Name der Sprachfamilie & Automaten    \\
         \hline\hline\hline
         0 & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}rekursiv aufzählbar & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}(N)DTM  \\
         \hline
         \cellcolor{lightgray!20}1 & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}kontext-sensitiv & NLBA \\
         \hline
         \cellcolor{lightgray!20}3 & regulär & \cellcolor{lightgray!20}(N)DEA \\
         \hline
         hu & ha & he \\
         \hline
      \end{tabularx}
   \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that seems a good solution - any way to prevent it from also affecting the header row? or to have rows of different/arbitrary height?

Comment: I wonder that too. The intent is to have the header row have a different height.

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Automate}` to neutralize the effect of the `S` prefix (and possibly add `\set length{\extrarowheight}{xxx pt}`) to not have a too great contrast in heights.

Comment: @greyshade: no, `cellspace` does not allow to change the minimal vertical spacings. But you can increase row heights  by inserting invisible rules  with  predefined height and depth in a cell.