# Dot-aligned table column with defined width

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, arrays, columns

I am trying to specify a custom column command, taking a width parameter and aligning the column by the decimal point of the content.

---

I am using the tabularx package to use columns with a pre-defined width

```
p{<width>}
```

The width is corrected by table margins with my defined `\COLW{<width>}` command (see [Table layout with tabularx (column widths: 50%|25%|25%)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84400/table-layout-with-tabularx-column-widths-502525) for reference)

What I am trying to achieve is a columend aligned along the decimal dot, which is provided by the 'S' column option of the `siunitx`. But this does not allow to specify the column width. I found the `array` package providing the `\centerdots` and `\endcenterdots` commands to define this behavior manually with a custom column type 'd' like

```
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{>{\centerdots\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{\endcenterdots}}
```

But somehow these commands are not properly recoginzed

```
undefined control sequence [...] \centerdots
```

Any ideas how to combine dot-aligned columns with explicit width specifications?

---

Minimal working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{array}      %should provide \centerdots command!?
\usepackage{tabularx}   %tabularx environment with fixed size columns
\usepackage{ragged2e}   %Provide \RaggedLeft and \RaggedRight commands
\usepackage{siunitx}    %Add 'S' option in tables to align along decimal point

\newcommand{\COLW}[1]{\dimexpr#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth} %defined column width with margin correction
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{#1}} %right-aligned column with given column width
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}} %left-aligned column with given column width
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} %centered column with given column width
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{>{\centerdots\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{\endcenterdots}} %dot-aligned column with given column width

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbtp!]
  \centering
  %this setup uses the 'S' column from siunitx package which properly centeres the content along the dot, BUT does not allow for column width specification
  \begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{|L{\COLW{0.25}}|C{\COLW{0.25}}|R{\COLW{0.25}}|d{\COLW{0.25}}|}
  %this setup uses \centerdots command from array package and defined column width, but doesn't work
  %\begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{|L{\COLW{0.25}}|C{\COLW{0.25}}|R{\COLW{0.25}}|S|}
    \hline
    left-aligned & centered & right-aligned & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{dot-aligned} \\ %multicolumn as workaround for non decimal number conflicting with 'S' option
    \hline 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 100.0   \\
    2 & 2 & 2 &  10.0   \\
    3 & 3 & 3 &   1.0   \\
    4 & 4 & 4 &   0.1   \\
    5 & 5 & 5 &   0.01  \\
    6 & 6 & 6 &   0.001 \\
    \hline  
  \end{tabularx}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is correct, but the standard `tabular` environment does not allow to specify the overall tabular width, which I would like to stretch to full `\textwidth`, hence I switched to `tabularx`.

Comment: On contrary : I do have some tables with more complex content, looking a bit packed with the dynamic width determination of the standard `tabular` environment, not using the fulll (or 90%) textwidth. So I now confirmed for myself that I can just use the standard `tabular` environment without specifying the full tabular width, but just defining N columns with `textwidth/N` columnwidth to achieve my desired behavior, which brings me back to the problem of the 'S' option not providing a width parameter option.

Comment: But this way I do not have an explicit control on the tabular width in terms of fraction of the full textwidth. I am editing a larger document, trying to follow the convention to use a common style with `0.9\textwidth` tables, so I would like to have the possibility to define the column width as fraction of textwidth adding up to 0.9. This should be possible by manually using the `\centerdots` command as shown in my MWE, but I am not able to make this work

Comment: updated answer with .9\textwidth table

Comment: This helps to reach my needs, thank you! For curiosity, how would I be able to define a custom column using the `\centerdots` option as it is proposed in the array package manual ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf with `\newcolumntype{d}{>{\centerdots}c<{\endcenterdots}}`

Comment: I don't see why `\centerdots` wouldn't work as `>{\centering\centerdots}p{3cm}<\endcenterdots` if you copied the definitions from the array package documentation (they are only given as example definitions in the doc, not actually defined in the package), as it notes there similar but improved versions are in my dcolumn package (but there again I assume `c` rather tahn `p` columns.

Comment: In my case this command is unkown when using the `array` package. Do you know where it is defined?

Comment: as I say it is not defined anywhere. the definition is in the text of the documentation just at the point you are reading, the code block at the bottom of page 2 is the definition you just need to copy from there into your document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `tabularx` unless you specify at least one `X` column to allow it to stretch that column to achieve the stated width.

Here I would just use `siunitx` (or `dcolumn`) and control the column widths by specifying (larger) formats for the numbers if that is required, for example the following where two of the columns have been forced wider.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{array}      %should provide \centerdots command!?

\usepackage{ragged2e}   %Provide \RaggedLeft and \RaggedRight commands
\usepackage{siunitx}    %Add 'S' option in tables to align along decimal point

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbtp!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{SSS[table-format=6.2]S[table-format=4.4]}
    \hline 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 100.0   \\
    2 & 2 & 2 &  10.0   \\
    3 & 3 & 3 &   1.0   \\
    4 & 4 & 4 &   0.1   \\
    5 & 5 & 5 &   0.01  \\
    6 & 6 & 6 &   0.001 \\
    \hline  
  \end{tabular} 

\bigskip

or to a specified width

\bigskip

  \begin{tabular*}{.9\textwidth}{
@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
SSS[table-format=6.2]S[table-format=4.4]
@{}}
    \hline 
    1 & 1 & 1 & 100.0   \\
    2 & 2 & 2 &  10.0   \\
    3 & 3 & 3 &   1.0   \\
    4 & 4 & 4 &   0.1   \\
    5 & 5 & 5 &   0.01  \\
    6 & 6 & 6 &   0.001 \\
    \hline  
  \end{tabular*} 

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I adapted this a little bit to work with my column definitions `\begin{tabular*}{0.9\textwidth}{|L{\COLW{0.225}}|C{\COLW{0.225}}|R{\COLW{0.225}}|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}S|@{}}`