# Tabularx does not span the full width of the page

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want to create a table that spans the full width of the page and where one column is half of the size of another column. As suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84401/147179), I use `tabularx` for that. For some reason, however, my table does not want to span the full page. In the MWE below, I gave the top row a color such that it is visualized that the cell width of the last column is not appropriate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}  % Half the size of X.

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXY}  % E.g., XYY does work...
    \hline
    % The first row is given a color to clearly show the cell width.
    \rowcolor{blue} A & B & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\ \hline
    a & b & c \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tabular with wrong cell width]

As one can see in the code, I use `X` for a normal column and `Y` for a column with half size. When I use columns `XYY`, it seems to work. Therefore, it seems pretty random to me. Could someone explain what is going wrong? What would be the correct way of creating columns the way I want (i.e., 40%, 40%, 20%)?

Comment: your tabularx is in error even without the color, you need to make sure that the sum of the widths of X columns is 3\hsize see the tabularx manual

Comment: you want 1.2\hsize  1.2\hsize  0.6\hsize

Comment: Aahh, I see! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply misused the coefficients in`\hsize=...`: they are not really coefficients of proportionality, but barycentric coefficients, i.e. their sum has to be equal to the total number of  X-type columns. In other words, here, you have to solve the linear system:
2x+y=3, x=2y.

Compare the result of your coefficients with the result of the correct coefficients. I added vertical rules to visualise the exact width of each column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}  % Half the size of X.

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXY}  % E.g., XYY does work...
    \hline
    % The first row is given a color to clearly show the cell width.
    \rowcolor{blue} A & B & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\ \hline
    a & b & c \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You phrased my thoughts perfectly: I thought that the `\hsize` could be used as coefficients of proportionality. I was wrong :). Many thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: You're welcome. You're not the unique case. That's why it is recommended to read carefully documentations (and ask if something is not quite clear)

Comment: That is a good advice and it would have saved me (and you) quite a lot of time as it is clearly written in section 4.3. So it is not that the documentation is not clear (it is clear), but because I failed to read it.