# Changing widths of specific columns in my long table

Tags: tables, xltabular

I'm dealing with a large table in my thesis.

I currently have four columns in my table, with small numbers in the 1st and 4th columns and long(ish) text in columns 2 and 3. Therefore I want columns 1 and 4 to be narrower than 2 and 4.

I have referred to the tabularx (I've been told it is also applicable to xltabular) documentation where it says:

```
{>{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X
>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
```

to change the X column sizes, but how would I do this for four columns?

My current table uses the following:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
   
  
    \hline
        \thead{Approx. \\ Raman shift\\ $(cm^{-1})$} & \textbf{Assignment} & \thead{What does this \\ mean for bone?} & \textbf{References} \\ \hline

*Main body of table*
 \end{xltabular}
```

I have referred to [Table layout with tabularx (column widths: 50%|25%|25%)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84400/table-layout-with-tabularx-column-widths-502525), but it didn't help.

Many thanks

Comment: You could use `{>{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X
>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X >{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X >{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}`. This will give you two pairs of equally wide columns with the wider pair having 3 times the width of the narrower column. Make sure the numbers add up to the number of `X` type columns (0.5+1.5+1.5+0.5=4)

Comment: @leandriis ah hello again! Ahh that makes sense. Would this go in the preamble before \begin{document} or inside the table code somewhere?

Comment: This is supposed to replace `{XXXX}`. As you can see, `>{\hsize=0.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}` is added in fromt of the first and the last `X` type column.

Comment: @leandriis oh of course! Thank you again for being so patient with my silly questions! My thesis is looking much better thanks to you!!

Comment: Is there a way to centre the information in these columns?

Comment: Assuming that you refer to horizontally centered contents, you can add `\centering\arraybackslash` as in `>{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X` and likewise for the wider columns.

Comment: If you want to adapt this format to multiple columns, it might be beneficial to define your own custom column command as `\newcolumntype{Z}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}`. You can later use it as follows: `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{Z{0.5}Z{1.5}Z{1.5}Z{0.5}}`.

Comment: What kind of citation style do you use? Is it a numeric one? Do you need linebreaks in the cells of the 4th column? You mentioned needing a narrow 4th column, so probably it is just easier to use `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{lXXl}` instead of having to worry about changing the relative widths of the columns.