# How to break line in a long column in tabular

Tags: tables, overleaf

I am trying to write a table that has 4 columns. However the 4th column is too large and i am writting texts inside this column and then the table goes outside the page. I would like to break a line using tabular everytime the text gets too large. This is an example:

```
\begin{table}     
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Study & CNN & Task & Optimization \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
authors &  CNN and Extreme Learning Machine & Image Classification & Ensemble methods with CNN.    
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The `makecell` package and its eponymous command provides the possibility to use  `\\`  in standard columns.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the tabularx and the booktabs package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could experiment with the `p type column` which allows auto line breaks

reference from -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166746/197451

[image]

```
\begin{table}     
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Study & CNN & Task & Optimization \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
authors &  CNN and Extreme Learning Machine & Image Classification & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}|}{\raggedright At oprette en server med bestemte regler som tillader folk at spille sammen. More Text more text More Text}  \\ 
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: this would be the right answer  but you posted the _wrong_ code copied from the question still using `l`

Answer (score 0):

To make your code compilable, a `\\` right before the last `\noalign{\smallskip}\hline` is missing. Having added this missing piece of code, let's focus on improving the output. With the help of the `tabularx` package you can easily make sure a table fits into the textwidth and horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package could be used instead of `\noalign{\smallskip}\hline`. Applying thouse changes, one ends up with:

[image]

Depending on your documentclass, the margin and font sizes as well as the individual contents of the table, you may want to alter the width of the `X` type columns. [Table layout with tabularx (column widths: 50%|25%|25%)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84400/134144) contains useful information on that. Text in narrower columns often looks better left aligned instead of justified and if you want left-aligned text in your `X` type columns, you could use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X`  instead of `X`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}     
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXlX}
\toprule
Study & CNN & Task & Optimization \\
\midrule
authors &  CNN and Extreme Learning Machine & Image Classification & Ensemble methods with CNN.\\    
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```